# CLLocationManager didVisit not working

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have created a class that handles some of the CoreLocation stuff and instantiated that in my AppDelegate, but I'm not receiving any didVisits as I drive around. What am I doing wrong?

AppDelegate

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let chauffeur = Chauffeur()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        // Request permission to present notifications
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)


        return true
    }
}
```

Chauffeur

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Chauffeur : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let clManager = CLLocationManager()

    private var viewController: UIViewController?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        clManager.delegate = self
    }

    func start() {
        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        println("status from start: \(status.rawValue)")

//        if status != CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied || status != CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted {
//            // make sure we can use location
//            if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
//                manager.startMonitoringVisits()
//            }
//        } else if (status == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined) {
//            manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
//        }

        switch status {
        case .AuthorizedAlways:
            println("monitoring")
            clManager.startMonitoringVisits()
        case .NotDetermined:
            println("request")
            clManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        case .AuthorizedWhenInUse, .Restricted, .Denied:
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Background Location Access Disabled", message: "In order for the app to work, please open this app's setting page and set location access to 'Always'", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let canceAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(canceAction)

            let openAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
                (action) in
                if let url = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
                }
            }
            alertController.addAction(openAction)
            viewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func stop() {

        clManager.stopMonitoringVisits()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        println("Location Status: \(status.rawValue)")
        if (status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways ||
            status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse) {
            manager.startMonitoringVisits()
        }

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didVisit visit: CLVisit!) {
        let realm = Realm()
        realm.write {
            realm.add(Visit(visit), update: false)
        }

        if visit.departureDate.isEqualToDate(NSDate.distantFuture() as! NSDate) {
            // A visit has begun, but not yet ended. User must still be at the place.
            println("Visit begun \(visit)")
            showNotification("Visit begun \(visit)")
        } else {
            // The visit is complete, user has left the place.
            println("Visit end \(visit)")
            showNotification("Visit end \(visit)")
        }
    }

    func showNotification(body: String) {
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertAction = nil
        notification.alertBody = body
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
    }

    func setViewController(viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.viewController = viewController
    }

}
```

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var chauffeur: Chauffeur!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let ad: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        chauffeur = ad.chauffeur
        chauffeur.setViewController(self)
    }

    @IBAction func toggleTracking(sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.on {
            println("on")
            chauffeur.start()
        } else {
            println("off")
            chauffeur.stop()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: do you enable Location updates in background mode

Comment: location services is always on

Comment: oh I did not enable Background Mode - Location Updates in capabilities.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check if you have enable Location in background modes from project settings -> Target -> Capabilities.

[image]

Comment: I tried this out today and I was still not getting any notifications or any write in my realm db. is there anything else wrong with my code?

Comment: experiencing the same issue - not getting any visits.

Comment: I'm inside an area which is defined as 'visit' and starting the app, have this bg mode enabled, starting monitoring for visits and not getting anything...

Comment: Don't do that. Location Updates as a background mode is needed for very specific use cases. You don't need it for visits.